# How can I mitigate the negative effects of refusing my manager's request to be complicit in a crime?

Tags: relationships

I am a junior software developer, and my colleague, a senior software developer, is transitioning from a work visa to permanent residency. There will be a gap in between the work visa expiring and the residency being granted, meaning my coworker will not be allowed to work for a short period.

My manager approached me and asked me to agree to allow my senior colleague to check in/out code and continue to work while using my credentials, so that all work he does will be under my name, and my coworker would receive a "bonus" equal to missed wages when he returned to work. I respect my coworker and sympathize with the hardship he will face with a period of forced unemployment, but I am unwilling to violate law and my own ethics to be complicit in this fraudulent work around.

During the conversation, my manager repeated "your decision will not affect your career here at the company" many times. This implied to me a subtext that my willingness to be complicit in this will indeed impact my career here.

I politely refused my manager's request, and I am now on the job market, but I expect to be looking for a job for many months to come.  What strategies can I use to mitigate the negative effects of my refusal on my career, especially with regards to my job security?

Comment: What actual negative effects have you seen? Deciding to look elsewhere was your choice. Has the company done anything else to cause you harm?

Comment: @KentAnderson This discussion happened two days ago, I have not seen any negative effects yet.  I hope I never do, but I want to be prepared.

Comment: I sympathize with your coworker.

Comment: @AndreiROM I do too, he's in a very tough spot.

Comment: Your colleague should check with the immigration authorities to see if there is any way to get an extension on the current work permit. At the end of my permanent resident interview, after deciding to approve my application, the US INS agent extended my temporary status to prevent a gap.

Comment: If your company wants to give said senior colleague a bonus when they return to work, I don't understand why they can't just make that happen without the dodgy check-in check-out code thing. Then everyone could avoid ethical problems.

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: @simbabque I am in the USA

Comment: @Brandin My manager will not give him a bonus if he doesn't work.  My manager is, uh, "self oriented".

Comment: There has to be more to this.  This sounds like a scam your manager and the other guy have cooked up, but for what purpose? You did right steering clear.

Answer (score 8):

You are worrying needlessly. You should take your manager at his word, the business has a lot more to lose than you do. And you did the right thing by refusing to compromise.

The business will find another solution, the onus is on them to do so, not you. I would be more concerned that they even asked you to contemplate such a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I was half asking to check my perspective.  I work on a series of 3 month contracts that have been renewed for over 3 years.  My fear is that the next contract will not be renewed.  I am currently unable to afford to be unemployed, so it is very important to me that I do not let myself go without work.

Answer (score 3):

To mitigate the effects of a **No** you should point out **alternatives**. A flat out "No" is unhelpful and nonconstructive. Maybe the alternatives you provide are not acceptable to the other person, but at least you showed good will and tried to find a solution.

> I don't have a good feeling with my signature under his work, especially when he's not allowed to work. But I can create an account for you and show you how to check in code, so you can check in whatever you want checked in yourself.

So maybe your boss does not want this. Maybe he does not want *his* signature involved either. But at least you showed that inside the legal limits you were willing to provide a constructive solution.

Comment: It's not his business and not his expertise to figure out how the company can have someone working for them who isn't legally allowed to work for them. He's a junior software developer, for heaven's sake. Even his manager is not in a position to do this because he has no idea what trouble his company could get into; this would be something for HR and legal department.

Comment: Offering any help is still involving myself in the crime.  I don't want to say "I won't help you commit this crime, but if you wanted to do it without me, this is how you would..."

Comment: Getting your boss an account and teaching him how to use it is absolutely legal and well within your job description. It is *not* within your job description to audit what your boss does with what you give him. Legally, you are not involved.

Comment: If you don't want to provide an alternative to "No" for whatever reason, I guess there is little you can do to mitigate the possible damage. Just hope that you are a good enough employee that your manager will keep you anyway. By what he said, I guess that's the case.

Comment: I've used this at least twice and both times the managers involved thought about the implications of *their* signature under the act and then cancelled it altogether. A flat out "No" would just have labelled me as negative and unhelpful without any thought process on their side.

Answer (score 0):

I get you are in a tough spot but you need to consider your career over near term employment.

Worst case scenario is you and the company are caught and you have fraud charges on you criminal record.  And it would likely be federal charges.  That would immediately show up on any background check.

Just by asking they put themselves at risk.  I would be concerned about repercussions but they have more to lose than you.  Do you have proof they asked you to commit fraud?

Comment: I have no proof that I was asked to commit fraud.